# Java program with paint method updates unintentionally as resize window

Tags: java, swing, timer, paint

I'm making simple animation with timer and paint method. But if I resize window, the animation update very faster than timer.

How can I stop this unintentional update?

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I stop this unintentional update?

Don't change the state of the animation from within the paint method, simply paint the current state.

You don't control when painting might occur and it could occur for any number of reasons, most of which you don't control, so you should NEVER modify state of your component or model from within any paint method.  Painting is for painting, nothing else...

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more information on how the painting system works in Swing